# how to use local variable to another function in python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
  def runscan(self):
     p = os.popen('LD_PRELOAD=/usr/libv4l/v4l1compat.so zbarcam
            /dev/video0','r')
     while True :
        code = p.readline().split(':')[1]
        print 'Got barcode:', code

  def input(self):
     self.entryc.insert(END, code)
```

how about this? i want use local 'code' to the next function to insert the result of barcode to my Tkinter entryBox.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass it as a parameter. change the definition of `input` to `def input(self, code)` and then as the last line of `runscan` call `input(code)`. A side note, you shouldn't use "input" as the name of a function, because it shadows the built-in `input` function, which is used for getting user input from the console.